# what version of IE is on my Windows 8.1 phone

Tags: internet-explorer

I have a Nokia 635 and want to know what version the stock IE browser is.  Is there some way to tell on the device?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lumia 635 comes with IE 11,you can check the version by going to internet explorer->settings->about.

Answer (score 4):

Windows Phone 8.1 comes with Internet Explorer 11 Update (which has [some additional changes over the desktop version](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn736066%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).

For completeness, Windows 10 Mobile comes with Edge, whilst Windows Phone 8.0 came with Internet Explorer 10

Answer (score 2):

Go here from that browser: http://www.whatsmybrowser.org

This is not technically *on your device*, but it'll still tell you on your device (as long as there's an internet connection).